# Unable Login Scratch Org event after changed password

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I try use Salesforce DX create a Scratch Org and use "sfdx force:org:open" command to open it.

Then I reset password for this user. And success reset it. But I can't use test.salesforce.com to login this Scratch Org, it always show error message: Please check your username and password.

May I ask is there any solution to fixed this issue?

I found same issue in force.com github but it not helped.
[https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/583](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/583%C2%A0)

Answer (score 2):

You can't login at test.salesforce.com to a Scratch Org. They are **not** Sandboxes. Use the URL for the scratch org (e.g. random-name-1234.my.salesforce.com). Using force:org:open should bring you back to the org, and you'll want to bookmark that URL for later access.

Comment: Is there any official documentation around this?   I have found that you can eventually login to the scratch org using test.salesforce.com, but it can take an hour or more before that login path actually works once a user is created.